# Chrome not letter display:table div take 100% height

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have two divs inside a container div using `display: flex`. One div is meant to simply contain text, and center it as closely to the center as possible. The other div contains responsive content (and image in the demo provided) that basically defines the height of the flex.

The first child div, contains layers of divs to emulate a table using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`, along with a `height: 100%` and `vertical-align: middle`. Before anyone mentions, I can't use an actual `<table>` due to problems with it supporting `position: relative` which my actual site utilizes.

In Firefox and Edge, everything loads as expected and works perfectly (or rather as good as Edge can muster). However, in Chrome, the div using `display: table` refuses to acknowledge it's `height: 100%`.

[Here is a demo of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/zde13ty7/)

Answer (score 1):

Using table tags (or `display:table`) for layouting purposes is wrong. You should only use tables for displaying tabular data.
What you want can be achieved with these mods to your CSS:

```
.flex-box {
    position: relative;
}
.table {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.table .table-cell {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The "cell" is now centered both horizontally and vertically. And it gets a vertical scrollbar if the content overflows the box.

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zde13ty7/3/).

Comment: Table *elements* should only be used for tabular data, because of the semantic implications. Using `display: table;` is fine if you want your layout to behave like a table without the semantic implications of using the actual table element.

Comment: While this option does work, it doesn't have the natural responsive fallback that it would have had using the `display:table` method. Granted a small change with a media query can resolve this.

Comment: @Billy From my point of view, the use of `display: table` is only a smart way of displaying tabular data on certain devices, while being able to display that content completely different on others, using media queries. However, it should not be used for layouting. What I mean is that it's sematically wrong to use `display:table` to position an element. At least this is what I believe.

Comment: CSS does not have any semantic value to it. That is why using `display: table` is fine but using an HTML `<table>` element is not (for non-tabular data).

Comment: So you think `display:table` was not implemented in CSS with the purpose of displaying tabular data. You think it was implemented so we could easily make children elements have 100% height of parent ones, right? I happen to disagree. And so do some browser development teams. Chrome devs happen to think CSS should have semantic value to it, as should all code. And I believe it's the right way to go.